# LocalStorage disappears in chrome after page refresh

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

It's fine on the first load but as soon as I refresh, despite it being available from the console, it's not visible in the applications tab.

What do I do about this?

I'm on version 57.0.2987.133

[image: Image of the issue]

Comment: https://crbug.com/701413 - fixed in canary 59 so far.

Comment: Still a bug in 58.0.3029.81

Answer (score 4):

As [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) mentioned, this is currently a bug on Chrome but fixed in canary 59. I'm on 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit) and still seeing the issue.

You can try on Safari and shouldn't see the issue.

Comment: Just noticed this issue too. Seems like a build is broken..odd enough, I just deleted my Canary

Comment: I just updated to chrome 59, and verified that it is fixed.